# Handle special characters in python

Tags: python, list, jenkins, unix, groovy

Hello I have jenkins pipeline configured, I have two stages  , firts one a get a list, it will be store  in a groovy variable  in this way:

```
IMAGES = sh(script:"python3 get_images.py --param1=\${PARAM_1} --param2=\${PARAM_2}", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

above code will get something like:

```
[("cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0", "tarfile-1.1.0.tar"), ("cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0", "tarfile-1.2.0.tar") ]
```

On the second stage, that groovy variable was passed to sh script ,

```
NOT_IMAGES = sh(script:"python3 filter_image.py --images=\'${IMAGES}'", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

but it passes that variable as as string (i dont know why) in this way, this is what i see in console:

```
python3 filter_out_image.py '--images=[(cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0, tarfile-1.1.0.tar), (cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0, tarfile-1.2.0.tar)]'
```

I want to get it back as a list `[("cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0", "tarfile-1.1.0.tar"), ("cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0", "tarfile-1.2.0.tar") ]`, I made different operations in groovy as well as python  but not success, I tried in groovy `IMAGES = IMAGES.split(',') as List` and also in python but this is the result:

```
>>> print (images)
[(cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0, tarfile-1.1.0.tar), (cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0, tarfile-1.2.0.tar) ]
>>> images.strip(',')
'[(cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0, tarfile-1.1.0.tar), (cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0, tarfile-1.2.0.tar) ]'
>>> images = images.strip(',')
>>> images.split(',')
['[(cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0', ' tarfile-1.1.0.tar)', ' (cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0', ' tarfile-1.2.0.tar) ]']
>>> keys = [pair[0] for pair in  images]
>>> print(",".join(keys))
[,(,c,l,o,u,d,/,i,m,a,g,e,_,s,t,o,r,e,d,_,d,o,c,k,e,r,:,1,.,1,.,0,,, ,t,a,r,f,i,l,e,-,1,.,1,.,0,.,t,a,r,),,, ,(,c,l,o,u,d,/,i,m,a,g,e,_,s,t,o,r,e,d,_,d,o,c,k,e,r,:,1,.,2,.,0,,, ,t,a,r,f,i,l,e,-,1,.,2,.,0,.,t,a,r,), ,]
```

Comment: your running a shell script. what are you expecting passing the variable to a shell script other than a string?

Comment: i want to pass the list in varible IMAGES =  [("cloud/image_stored_docker:1.1.0", "tarfile-1.1.0.tar"), ("cloud/image_stored_docker:1.2.0", "tarfile-1.2.0.tar") ], example : NOT_IMAGES = sh(script:"python3 filter_image.py --images=\'${IMAGES}'", returnStdout: true).trim()

Comment: yeah but a shell script doesnt know what a python list is. how it the shell suppose to interpolate the python list inside the shell to then pass that to the python3 call